# Arrayformula to pull the minimum value in a column based on cell contents of another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to find a way to get my `minifs` formula to work in an `arrayformula` in google sheets.

I have two sheets - Summary and Data. On Data, I have a list of names in Col A that duplicate. Col B has a list of labels that correspond to dates in Col C. On Summary, I have a query that is pulling a list of unique names from a third tab to Col A. In Col B, I'm trying to pull in the minimum date for each person that is not an arrival date.

Data

```
Col A         Col B            Col C
James       departure        1/1/2019
Sarah       arrival          12/3/2018
Sarah       departure        3/12/2019
David       departure        5/23/2019
James       departure        12/2/2018
David       departure        4/7/2019
David       arrival          11/18/2018
```

I know that inherently the min formula doesn't work in an `arrayformula` without some additional complex formula language that I admittedly don't have the skills to do.

The formula I'm using now is

```
=MINIFS(Data!C2:C,Data!A2:A,A2,Data!B2:B,"<>*arrival*")
```

This formula works as expected. I'd just really like to be able to use an `arrayformula` as my list of unique names constantly grows every day. I'd expect the output of the formula on Summary tab to be:

```
Col A           Col B
James         12/2/2018
David         4/7/2019
Sarah         3/12/2019
```

Link to example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_eXKkiPpZwmOSmB3CBkSx_usP05J7hKdZlecQ0--Wk/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Lindsay and welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you spent a while working on aligning your tables for the question - and while it looks nice, for future reference it's usually easier to format those kinds of things by wrapping your table in triple-backticks! That treats it as a code-block, which preserves whitespace :) You didn't do anything wrong - just a tip to help you out in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SORT(QUERY(Data!A2:C, "where B = 'Departure'"), 1, 1, 3, 1), 3, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! I did not think to use the sort function.